# How to add custom column to magento cms page grid

Tags: magento2, grid, cms

How is it possible to add custom colunm with data from another table to magento cms page grid?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is UI component called Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml

You need to extend it in your custom module ({your namespace}/{your_module_name}/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml)

Here is section about UI components http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html

Comment: Thank you. I have extended the cms_page_listing.xml. Now the question is how would I overwrite the cms grid collection and populate newly created columns with my custom data. Secondly, how would I save them when the user changes their values?